# Laravel : retrieve "Many To Many" associations based on a version criteria

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.4 to develop a small tool that shall keep track of various objects along their lives. A single object is identified by it's uuid. Uuid is not unique as an object can have multiple versions.

Performance is not a must, as the number of object is small.

The database is more or less as follow :
[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIx5W.png)

I want to be able to select all *obj2* linked to a specific *obj1* for the current version of a project like so:

```
$obj1->obj2s()->allForProjectLastRevision($project_id);
```

I also want to be able to select all *obj1* for the current version of a project like that:

```
Obj1::allForProjectLastRevision($project_id);
```

And I have the following code for now.

```
<?php

abstract class VersionableModel extends Model
{

    public function versions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Version');
    }

    public function scopeAllForProjectLastRevision($query, $project_id)
    {
        $query->whereHas('versions', function($query) use($project_id) {
             $query->whereHas('project', function($query) use($project_id) {
                     $query->where('projects.id', $project_id)
                           ->whereColumn ('projects.current_version_id', 'versions.id');
                   });
        });
        return $query->get();
    }
}

class Obj1 extends VersionableModel
{
        public function obj2s()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Obj2');
        }
}

class Version extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    public function current_version()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version', 'current_version_id');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the *scopeAllForProjectLastRevision* doesn't return the expected result.

The result is a list containing all the *obj2s* linked to a specific *obj1* **not limited to the current version of the project**.

Am'I missing something?